# Splitting the string url in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I am trying to call the backend api which results in the details of the specific product based on id for example the api is `http://localhost:54729/api/product/1` the `1` in the api is the id of the specific product. I am using `redux` and `axios` to get the data from the api.

**EDIT:**
The response from the api from which I am getting is the following

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "TestProductAzure",
        "description": "<p>While working with the EF Core Code-First approach, we create the classes for our domain entities first. Later, we’ll create the database from our code by using migrations. This is the opposite of the Database-First approach where we design our database first and then create the classes which match our database design.In the EF Core Code-First approach, we have full control over the code and the database is just a store without any logic. This approach is helpful in situations where we are starting with the development of a new project and we don’t have a clear picture of how our database should look like yet.We don’t have to worry about creating and updating the database. We can just make the changes in our code and then sync everything easily with the database. The important thing to note is that the manual changes that we make to the database could be lost during migration. So we should make changes to the code only.</p>",
        "owner": "Seeded Company",
        "link": null,
        "url": "http://localhost:54729/api/product/1",
        "type": "Internal",
        "rank": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "Support | example.com",
        "description": null,
        "owner": null,
        "link": "/search/product?url=https://www.example.com/support/",
        "url": "https://www.exampl.com/support/",
        "type": "External",
        "rank": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "TestProductForAzure",
        "description": null,
        "owner": "Seeded Company",
        "link": null,
        "url": "http://localhost:54729/api/product/3",
        "type": "Internal",
        "rank": 0
    },
```

The above response is the response when someone search something with the `keyword`. Now what I want if the user clicks on the url that has the api like `http://localhost:54729/api/product/` I want to check the last number of the api i.e. the id and get the response from that forexample, if the user clicks on `http://localhost:54729/api/product/2` . I want to pass the `id` `2` to the function which will then get pass from action and axios.get give the response.

My Action look like this

```
export function detailsProduct(id) {
  const token = userService.getToken();
  console.log(token);
  const api = `/product/${id}`;

  axios
    .get(apiBaseUrl + api, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } })

    .then(res => {
      console.log("helloProductDetails", apiBaseUrl + api);
      try {
        store.dispatch({
          type: PRODUCT_DETAILS,
          payload: res
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("error", err);
      }
    });
```

My Reducer look like this:

```
 case PRODUCT_DETAILS:
      console.log(
        "action",
        action,
        "actionPayload",
        action.payload,
        "state",
        state
      );

      return {
        ...state,
        products: action.payload,
        loading: false,
        totalRecords: action.payload.length
      };
```

and my `.jsx` react look like this

```
function onClickHandler() {
  console.log("calling Details Product, HardCodedly");
  detailsProduct(1);
}

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="s130">
        {/* <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-8 col-sm-12 col-md-7"> */}
        <div className="col-lg">
          <div className="container">
            {result.type === "Internal" ? (
              <Link to={DoctorProductLocation.path} onClick={onClickHandler}>
                <h3>{result.title}</h3>
              </Link>
            ) : (
              //Try With OnClick Function
              <a href={result.url} target="_blank">
                <h3>{result.title}</h3>
              </a>
            )});
```

As you did notice , I'm sending the id hardcoded for now just to check if I am getting the information, which is working fine. But All I want to do is that when I click on the response it will automatically check the `id` and send us the response of that.

I thought of splitting the url until the `id` and pass it to the function action. But I don't know How? Or else if you have any other good idea, I will be thankful to you.

Comment: you want to take out id from url?

Comment: This has nothing to do with redux or axios. Are you using any router libraries that expose the URL data?

Comment: @VahidAkhtar and jonrsharpe .. I have edit the question.

Comment: @Khan you haven't shared enough info. please share your complete code of component where you are mapping/iterating.

Comment: Assuming you re-create API endpoint URL with `apiBaseUrl+api` where `api` depends on `id` you wish to extract, wouldn't that be easier to pass the entire `url` (present within search results properties) to your action creator as a payload?